# What is the difference between ltsp-server and ltsp-server-standalone packages?

Tags: ltsp

What is the difference between `ltsp-server` and `ltsp-server-standalone` packages? What packages must I use for setting up an `ltsp-cluster` root server? According to this link:

[UbuntuLTSP/LTSP-Cluster - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/LTSP-Cluster)

> the root server use the ltsp-server and dhcp3-server packages ..

But, I think `ltsp-server-standalone` and `isc-dhcp-server` packages is the newer one.

Is that okay if I use `ltsp-server-standalone` and `isc-dhcp-server` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete LTSP server with all the bells and whistles you need `ltsp-server-standalone`. It includes a DHCP server, remote device access using ltspfs, remote sound using pulseaudio, network swap using NBD and more.  [Full list of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ltsp-server-standalone). You can see amongst them  `ltsp-server` as it is a dependency. It will install `isc-dhcp-server (4.2.4-1ubuntu10)`.

`ltsp-server` is just the basic environment with minimal features necessary to build an LTSP environment. It will suggest amongst others a DHCP server. [Full list of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ltsp-server). It will also suggest `isc-dhcp-server (4.2.4-1ubuntu10)`.

So the answer is: yes, that is OK if you want to do that.